# How to declare and use public functions and subroutines in Worksheet code

Tags: vba, excel, code-hinting

I have a public function declared in one of my worksheet modules:

```
Public Function isValidContract(contract As String) As Boolean
    ' Code reads cell values from the worksheet and determines
    ' if passed-in contract is one of them.
End Function
```

I'd like to be able to access it from other modules and Class modules. I've tried the following:

```
Public Sub someRandomSubInAntoherModule()

    Dim contract As String
    Dim sh as Worksheet

    ' Code that sets contract
    Set sh = Sheets("Matrix")
    If Not sh.isValidContract(contract) Then
        ' blah
    End If

End Sub
```

But I get a compile error: "Method or data member not found", probably because I declared `sh` as a **Worksheet** object, and the **Worksheet** object doesn't have an `isValidContract()` method. But I want to use the `isValidContract()` method defined in my *Matrix* worksheet.

The only way I can get it to work is to declare `sh` as an **Object**. But then I don't get the nifty little code hints when I type

```
sh.
```

Is there any way to dimension `sh` such that I get the code hints for the Worksheet object *and* my specific *Matrix* code?

Comment: Why is the function in a worksheet module?

Comment: Because it's specific to that particular sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - so I just figured it out.

Change the "Excel name" of the sheet to something that makes sense... in this case, I renamed *Sheet1* to *MatrixSheet* by editing its Properties.

Then in the client code:

```
Public Sub someRandomSubInAntoherModule()

    Dim contract As String
    Dim sh as MatrixSheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Matrix")

    ' Code that sets contract
    If Not sh.isValidContract(contract) Then
        ' blah
    End If

End Sub
```

It compiles, I get code hints, it's great.

Comment: You can just use `MatrixSheet.isValidContract(contract)` without declaring a variable of that type.  The `MatrixSheet` object is already instantiated in your workbook's VB Project.